# fedena : rake aborted school not selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, fedena

I was installing fedena on **ubuntu** installed on **wsl** and the database **creation** and **migration** was successful but when run the command `rake fedena:plugins:install_all` to install the plugins. in the middle this error pops up that `school Not Selected` and here is the error trace.

```
School Not Selected
/root/fedena/vendor/plugins/acts_as_multi_school/lib/multischool/read.rb:46:in `with_school'
/root/fedena/vendor/plugins/acts_as_multi_school/lib/multischool/read.rb:22:in `find_with_school'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1954:in `find'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1954:in `find_or_create_by_config_key'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1940:in `send'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1940:in `method_missing_without_paginate'
/root/fedena/vendor/plugins/will_paginate/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:170:in `method_missing'
/root/fedena/app/models/configuration.rb:90:in `find_or_create_by_config_key'
/root/fedena/db/seeds.rb:26
/root/fedena/db/seeds.rb:2:in `each'
/root/fedena/db/seeds.rb:2
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/databases.rake:215
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/root/fedena/lib/tasks/fedena_plugin_install.rake:31
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/rake:19
```

the code causing this error appears to be this code:

```
module MultiSchool

  module Read

    def self.extended (base)
      
      eigen_class = class << base;self;end
      
      ["find","count","sum","exists?"].each do |method|
        
        matches = method.match /([\w\d_]+)(\?|!|=)?$/
        
        eigen_class.send :define_method, "#{matches[1]}_with_school#{matches[2]}" do |*args|

          options = args.extract_options!
          skip_multischool = options.delete :skip_multischool
          args << options unless options.empty?
          
          result = if skip_multischool || Thread.current[:skip_multischool].present?
            send("#{matches[1]}_without_school#{matches[2]}",*args)
          else
            with_school do
              send("#{matches[1]}_without_school#{matches[2]}",*args)
            end
          end
          result
        end

        eigen_class.send :alias_method_chain, method, :school
      end

    end

    def skip_multischool
      Thread.current[:skip_multischool]=true
      yield
    ensure
      Thread.current[:skip_multischool]=nil
    end

    private

    def with_school      
      target_school = MultiSchool.current_school
      if target_school.nil?
        raise MultiSchool::Exceptions::SchoolNotSelected,"School Not Selected"
      else
        with_scope(:find => {:conditions  => {:school_id  => target_school.id}}) do
          yield
        end
      end
    end

  end

end
```

looks the `MultiSchool.current_school` is returning `nil` which sets the variable `target_school` to `nil` so the above exception occurs of `school not selected` but I don't know where to from here?

Could you please help me out this issue.

Comment: Since you mentioned [mysql], please provide the generated SQL.

Comment: @RickJames I think `module MultiSchool` code I have shared above is an abstraction of the mysql commands used. this is a rails project.

Comment: solved it thanks.